# WCF does not generate partial classes on the client side of the project

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2017

There is such a class:

```cs
[DataContract]
    public sealed partial class Worker : IKeyedModel
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get => this.id; set => this.id = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Test { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get => this.firstName; set => this.firstName = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string LastName { get => this.lastName; set => this.lastName = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get => this.dateOfBirth; set => this.dateOfBirth = value; }
```

Wcf is also available for server and client communication. I connect the service in my project and I want to use this partial class in the client code, but the link to the service does not generate this class.
A year ago, I did everything exactly the same, but it worked.
I would be grateful for any help.

```cs
namespace TestManagerClient.WcfReference {


    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="WcfReference.IService")]
    public interface IService {

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IService/TestMethod", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IService/TestMethodResponse")]
        void TestMethod();

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IService/TestMethod", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IService/TestMethodResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task TestMethodAsync();
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public interface IServiceChannel : TestManagerClient.WcfReference.IService, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public partial class ServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TestManagerClient.WcfReference.IService>, TestManagerClient.WcfReference.IService {

        public ServiceClient() {
        }

        public ServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName) {
        }

        public ServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public ServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public ServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public void TestMethod() {
            base.Channel.TestMethod();
        }

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task TestMethodAsync() {
            return base.Channel.TestMethodAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the structure of the generated client proxy class, The TestMethod do not reference the Datacontract class. So it is reasonable that the auto-generated the proxy does not contain data contract. We could add the Data Contract class to the parameter of the TestMethod, and then verify the result.
DataContract example.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.